# Is it possible to go back one level of breadcrumbs using hotkey in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode has breadcrumbs feature that looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to go back one level in these breadcrumbs using a hotkey? So in the case above, I am inside `propTypes`. I press hotkey and I go to `BatchTypesTable`.

I can achieve this already by clicking on the breadcrumb itself but I want to have a hotkey to do this.

Comment: view in the keybindings if there is a `breadcrumbs` command that does what you want

Comment: There are a bunch of `breadcrumbs` commands.  Depends where you are starting from.  If focus is on the breadcrumbs list just leftarrow.  If focus is on the editor you'll either have to do a couple of keybindings or make a macro to do that.

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS, my keyboard workflow is:

- open breadcrmb with <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>
- then navigate the top level with <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>
- use plain arrows to navigate inside the drop-down list

So, I guess on windows top-level navigation would be <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>?

Relevant VSC documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved#_breadcrumb-keyboard-navigation). Although it seems to be incomplete and partially incorrect?

Comment: I use Linux and instead of option+⬅️, option+➡️ keys it is ctrl+⬅️, ctrl+➡️ keys. there is a big chance that windows be the same.